# Проблема в написании кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Простите за глупый вопрос, но почему код выдаёт ошибку:

```py
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

***Код написан без ошибок:***

```py
gender = input('Ввидите пол. Мужчина,Женщина:')
man_height = input('Ввидите рост:')

if gender == "Мужчина ":
    r = int(((gender * 4 / 2.54)-128)*0.453)
elif gender == "Женщина ":
    r = int(((gender * 3.5 / 2.54)-108)*0.453)    
print('Ваш идеальный вес' + str(r))
```

Comment: Вы ввели строку, которая не совпадает ни с `"Мужчина "`, ни с `"Женщина "` (с учетом пробела в конце). Лучше убирать пробелы из `gender` справа и слева при помощи метода `strip()`. И не понятно почему у вас пол участвует в вычислениях вместо роста.

Comment: Внутри блоков `if`, `else` создается временная переменная `r`, которая удаляется при выходе из блока. Объявите ее заранее, перед `if`, к примеру `r = 0`, чтобы область видимости была вне `if/else`

Comment: `r = int(((gender * 3.5 / 2.54)-108)*0.453) ` Наверное вы имели ввиду `man_height` вместо `gender`?

Comment: Фраза "код написан без ошибок" про код, который выдает ошибку, это какая-то оторванная от реальности самонадеянность.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что если пользователь неправильно ввёл пол, условия пропускаются и начинает выполняться строка:

```py
print('Ваш идеальный вес' + str(r))
```

В коде выше есть переменная `r`, но так как условия не выполнились, она не определена, о чём Вам и сообщает ошибка.

Для того чтобы избежать этого, **добавьте блок `else`**, чтобы обработать крайний случай.

---

Но это не решит проблему работоспособности кода, у Вас ещё много ошибок (как минимум, неверные типы из-за ошибки в формуле), поэтому предлагаю свою реализацию на основе Вашего кода:

```py
def get_ideal_weight(gender: str, height: int) -> int:
    if gender == 'Мужчина':
        ideal_weight = int(((height * 4 / 2.54) - 128) * 0.453)
    elif gender == 'Женщина':
        ideal_weight = int(((height * 3.5 / 2.54) - 108) * 0.453)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"{gender} not in ('Мужчина', 'Женщина')")
    return ideal_weight


def main():
    gender = input('Введите Ваш пол (Мужчина/Женщина): ')
    height = int(input('Введите Ваш рост: '))

    ideal_weight = get_ideal_weight(gender, height)
    print(f'Ваш идеальный вес {ideal_weight} кг.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -3):

В вашем коде имеются следующие ошибки:

1. вы не конвертируете рост человека в float/int, имея строку и проводя над ней операцию деления (и то, в вашей версии кода вы делите gender на что-то, а надо, видимо, man_height)
2. Конкретно ваша ошибка означает, что переменная не была объявлена. А не была она объявлена, т.к. не одно из условий не сработало

Исправленная версия вашего кода:

```
gender = input('Введите пол [Мужчина, Женщина]:')
man_height = float(input('Введите рост:'))

if gender == "Мужчина":
    r = int(((man_height * 4 / 2.54)-128)*0.453)

elif gender == "Женщина":
    r = int(((man_height * 3.5 / 2.54)-108)*0.453)

print('Ваш идеальный вес ' + str(r))
```

Comment: Почему для мужчины сравнивается с полным словом, а для женщины с сокращенным, и все в нижнем регистре, хотя примеры ввода в `input` с большой буквы?

Comment: ну, тут дело вкуса :/

Comment: Не дело вкуса, а введение предполагаемого пользователя в заблуждение, из-за чего он тем более не сможет правильно ввести данные. Это не исправление. Поэтому минус.

Comment: Не оскорбляйте, пожалуйста, участников. Критика Вашего кода вполне обоснована, поддерживаю @insolor.

Comment: вы могли сделать правку просто. Зачем конфликтовать

Comment: @SaharVkusni, добавьте `else` в котором нужно ругаться, что введен неправильный пол, иначе у вас будет такая же ошибка как у автора (думаю, поэтому вам минусы и поставили)